# jQuery FadeIn efect changing image

Tags: jquery, html

I have problem. I trying to change last image on div with new one by this code:

```
var rand = Math.floor(8*Math.random()+1);
$("#foto-"+ rand).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $("#foto-"+ rand).html('<img style="position: relative;" height="100%" src="slides/'+ Math.floor(fotos*Math.random()+1) +'.jpg" />');
});
```

This code change image, but no effect displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `fadeIn` like that. You can use `fadeIn` to make an item visible, but not to make changes to the DOM. You should use `animate` for custom animations as I demonstrate here: http://jsfiddle.net/KMuN3/.

However, in this situation, `animate` is probably overkill since you really just need to fade out and in. Just do this instead:

```
var rand = Math.floor(8*Math.random()+1);
$("#foto-"+ rand).fadeOut();
$("#foto-"+ rand).html('<img style="position: relative;" height="100%" src="slides/'+ Math.floor(fotos*Math.random()+1) +'.jpg" />');
$("#foto-"+ rand).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rand = Math.floor(8*Math.random()+1);
$("#foto-"+ rand).hide();
$("#foto-"+ rand).html('<img style="position: relative;" height="100%" src="slides/'+ Math.floor(fotos*Math.random()+1) +'.jpg" />');
$("#foto-"+ rand).fadeIn("slow");
```